# I want to implement a lasso tool in react-native-sketch-canvas

Tags: javascript, react-native, canvas, react-native-sketch-canvas

I have implemented a canvas draw feature using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@kichiyaki/react-native-sketch-canvas. Now I want to implement a lasso tool where i can select an area in the canvas and i can cut, copy or delete the drawing in that particular area. has anyone implemented anything like this?

I have tried selecting an area but i am not able to get the coordinates or the drawings inside it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One pretty rough idea, which outsources the most difficult math to SVG would be to:

1. create an SVG path using your touch events
2. use SVG to fill it with white
3. Convert it to a black and white lasso shape image
4. Create a selection copy of the source image
5. Loop through every pixel of lasso shape image and if the pixel is white, in corresponding pixel..:

   1. ...in source image, set pixel alpha to clear (0)
   2. ...in selection copy image, set pixel alpha to opaque (1)